I can't import moviepy
Trying to import moviepy to use it to extract audio from video files, but i'm getting an invalid syntax error, or it can't find the program. I think pip is installed correctly but I'm not sure. (i'm running Python 3.12 on windows 11, this is happening in the IDLE shell)
following a tutorial i saw online, i first tried
py -m pip --version, got an invalid syntax error.
Then proceeded to get the same invalid syntax error for every variation of code I tried. Got a name error when I called help(pip),  but it was listed in the available modules.
The syntax i found online was pip install moviepy but this also resulted in a syntax error.
I'm very new to coding, have no idea what i'm doing wrong.

If you are typing those commands inside the IDLE shell then that is why you get the syntax errors. The IDLE shell is actually running the Python interpreter. You need to type the pip install command(s) in a normal Windows cmd shell.

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+SyntaxError

Welcome to Stack Overflow, You can't run pip in IDLE shell. To install a module in windows 11, you need to open cmd or powershell and run pip install module_name. Don't run pip in IDLE shell.
I also suggest you to use a virtual environment to manage modules between projects. venv tutorial

ah yes, right. that makes sense haha. thank you for the suggestion!

You have to install modules via CMD, not IDLE.Go to your search bar and type in CMD. You will see Command Prompt. Click Run as Administrator. Just press yes if a prompt shows up. Then in the search bar, type python, make sure to right-click the app, not IDLE and press open file location. You will see a bunch of shortcuts, with the app already selected, right-click and again click open file location. Here, go to Scripts. Now, copy the directory and paste it in CMD. Then run pip install moviepy

ah, gotcha, thanks!
